# Getting exception when i use YoutubePlayer.loadVideo

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am getting exception when i invoke YoutubePlayer.loadVideo() method.

Following is the code i am using:

```
  onInitializedListener=new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            Log.d("onInitializationFailure","Unable to load");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            //player.loadVideo(strVideoURL);
            player.cueVideo(strVideoURL,1);
        }
    };
```

Following is the exception i am getting in androidstudio(because of this exception it shows only blank black screen, after that i am not able to invoke any other videos also):

```
01-08 23:00:11.868 32736-3385/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Failed to construct CronetEngine. Using fallback Java implementation.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Disk cache storage path already in use
        at org.chromium.net.impl.CronetUrlRequestContext.<init>(SourceFile:49)
        at awpo.a(SourceFile:5)
        at awkn.a(SourceFile:18)
        at vot.a(SourceFile:24)
        at vov.get(SourceFile:16)
        at autw.get(SourceFile:9)
        at lfx.M(SourceFile:140)
        at lfh.get(SourceFile:4)
        at vrf.c(SourceFile:78)
        at vrf.run(SourceFile:27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at vgy.run(SourceFile:12)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Can anybody help me on the above problem? What i observed is, when i click on my video it is playing fine. When i click on the second video, i am getting black screen and from there on i am not getting any videos are working, getting the same above error.

Answer (score 1):

I lately observed i am getting null "strVideoURL" when i am navigating between activities. So the reason we are getting blank screen.

Sharing here, as it might help look their mistake.

Thanks